# como hacer que se identifiquen palabras claves dentro de un texto con php + laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, meta-tags

estoy intentando programar un sistema con `Laravel` para gestionar los informes de las reuniones que se realizan. Este sistema seria un modulo de un sistema de gestión que ya ha desarrollado en `Laravel 5.5`. EL informe lo redacto en el sistema utilizando `CKEDITOR` que me facilita mucho el trabajo. Ahora voy a mi problema. En las reuniones se toman diferentes acuerdos y quisiera implementar algo que me permita recorrer todo el informe que se redactó y detecte palabras o etiquetas que indique que lo que viene a continuación es un acuerdo y me salve en una tabla de mi base de datos el contenido de esta etiqueta o palabra clave que indique que se trata de un acuerdo.

Existe algo desarrollado que me permita tomarlo de base para poder hacer esto. Pueden ayudarme amigos

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones o recomendaciones terminan cerradas

Comment: es que una opion puede generar una solución a un problema determinado

Comment: solo necesito saber como programar el codigo para intentar resolver mi problema

Comment: Si pero la zona de respuestas lastinosamente no es para preguntas basadas en eso, si requieres opiniones te recomiendo elimines esto por que terminará cerrada y mejor vayas al [chat] donde será mejor recibida tu duda

Comment: y donde se escribe la duda en cualquier room__

Comment: En la sala principal (**SO en español**), todos los que usan el chat entran ahi y podrán leer tu pregunta